# How to configure CORS for Akamai CDN on Azure?

Tags: azure, cdn, akamai

I want to configure CORS in Azure Portal for an Akamai (S2) CDN. From what I can gather, I think I need to go to the storage account and configure CORS from there. But is it the Blob service, or File service tab? Also, is there any documentation on how to configure CORS for Akamai in Azure Portal? I couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Do you need CORS? Wouldn't a CDN do the download from a server process and not the browser?

Comment: Yes, I need CORS :) Another system is loading stuff from the CDN (not a browser), but it respects CORS and does script execution. I need CORS.